# Making changes to Python and DJango files on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi

So I am running django on my Ubuntu instance. I am new to using ubuntu but I am running this very sensitive server where I can not afford to allow it to crash. I plan on making some changes to some py and html files but was wondering what the following steps would be to allow for a smooth update. I am running Django, uwsgi, Nginx and Supervisord. My partner had left with very little notes who would usually be in charge of this all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have some method for testing changes before they go live. You should also back-up certain things so that any changes can be reverted if something unexpected happens.

There are a few different ways to go about testing changes. It would be very helpful if you cold run a mirror copy of your server on your local machine. Ideally, you would test your server locally as either an Ubuntu virtual machine or a PC running Ubuntu. Another possibility would be to launch a second instance of your server. There might already be an image of your server stored on your cloud provider. With the second instance, you could test your changes. Alternatively, you could move your public IP address from the first instance to the second. I would note that this would create a few minutes of downtime, where as updating your existing server (presuming everything goes smoothly), should only create, about, six seconds of downtime.

Comment: Thank you. The test server is very helpful. I have been making changes on the same server and its been very risky as crashes prevent any work to be done.